# IEC 61968 standard isn't "standardized"?

Tags: standards, iso, metering

I am currently trying to adapt to IEC protocol. I'm looking at this document: IEC 61968-9 – Interface Standard for Meter Reading & Control.

Messages described at begging of the document(UML schemas) don't match XSD schemas at the end of document. Also, most of the messages aren't described almost at all. For example, how do I pass argument in EndDeviceControl messages, when I want to set value of something on EndDevice?
As this being called standard, I expected to see precisely described protocol, like RFCs are. What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you ever found answer for this? I have similar experience with IEC 61968-9. And almost every vendor implements it differently because many things are either ambiguous, wrong or not normative by design. Are you on 2nd edition?

Answer (score 1):

This is a very late answer but I wanted to record this in case anyone runs into the same problems. There is a companion document IEC 61968-900 ("Part 900: Guidance for implementation of IEC 61968-9") that attempts to fill in the holes left by the 61968-9 standard. To quote from -900:

*While IEC 61968-9 defines the various data items from which the request and response messages are constructed, it is less prescriptive about the corresponding message flows – that is, how a complete message exchange looks. This document provides examples of typical message exchange patterns.
. . .
This technical report is a companion document to the official standard. It is written from the viewpoint of a software developer or systems integrator who is tasked with implementing IEC 61968-9.*